# Want to show $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges by cauchy condensation for $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Anyone know of a series I can bound the other one by? This one:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \frac{1}{k^{2p}}$$

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: @Shaun I dont have much ,  just trying to use the compariso ntest, i wrote out some terms of that series thats really all. i want to find a series to bound it above by.

Comment: So the goal here is to use a more advanced theorem (without proof), to prove a much simpler statement? Why not use the integral test? I'm sorry, but I find it incredulous that one would use more technical theorems to prove much simpler statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in the case of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$$ you have that $f(k)=k^{-p}$ (using the notation of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)). So according to the Cauchy condensation test the above series converges iff the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^kf(2^k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k(2^k)^{-p}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2^k)^{1-p}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2^{1-p})^k \tag1$$ converges. But, since $1-p<0$ we have that $$2^{1-p}<1$$ hence the RHS in $(1)$ is a geometric series of a term which is less than $1$ and therefore converges.

Comment: thank you!! that helps a lot.

Comment: @terribleatmath You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that if $a_k=k^{-p}$ then $2^ka_{2^k}=2^k 2^{-pk}=2^{(1-p)k}$.